# LibreOffice 5 pdf security disable extract pages but pdfsam can split pdf file

Tags: security, pdf, libreoffice, extract

i export doc to pdf with security options not to extract pages (none). But i can split the pdf to non secure pdfs. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adobe PDF security: is it really just an "honor code"?](http://superuser.com/questions/1113125/adobe-pdf-security-is-it-really-just-an-honor-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PDF spec:

> ...a conforming reader technically has access to the entire contents
>   of the document. **There is nothing inherent in PDF encryption that
>   enforces the document permissions specified in the encryption
>   dictionary**. Conforming readers shall respect the intent of the
>   document creator by restricting user access to an encrypted PDF file
>   according to the permissions contained in the file.

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113125/adobe-pdf-security-is-it-really-just-an-honor-code) might be relevant too

Comment: so pdfsam does not respect the security options, that is i understand.

Comment: Yes, and likewise any other PDF reader/consumer could decide to do the same so you shouldn't rely on that